# How to run a stored procedure in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to run this stored procedure

```
DECLARE
  P_TICKER_SERIAL VARCHAR2(200);
  P_SECTOR_CODE   VARCHAR2(200);
  P_SOURCE_ID     VARCHAR2(200);
  P_COUNTRY_CODE  VARCHAR2(200);
  P_FILTER_TYPE   NUMBER;
  CUR_OUT         SYS_REFCURSOR;
  dbUserTable     DBUSER%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  P_TICKER_SERIAL :='14232';
  P_SECTOR_CODE   := '15';
  P_SOURCE_ID     := 'TDWL';
  P_COUNTRY_CODE  := 'SA';
  P_FILTER_TYPE   := 1;

  PKG_name.GET_user(
    P_TICKER_SERIAL => P_TICKER_SERIAL,
    P_SECTOR_CODE   => P_SECTOR_CODE,
    P_SOURCE_ID     => P_SOURCE_ID,
    P_COUNTRY_CODE  => P_COUNTRY_CODE,
    P_FILTER_TYPE   => P_FILTER_TYPE,
    CUR_OUT         => CUR_OUT
  );
  open CUR_OUT;
  LOOP
    FETCH CUR_OUT INTO dbUserTable;
    dbms_output.put_line(dbUserTable.email);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE CUR_OUT;
END;
 /
```

But it gives me this error

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 8, column 15:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBUSER' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 8, column 15:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 24, column 2:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 24, column 2:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 26, column 24:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 26, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 27, column 28:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 27, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Any one knows  what is wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: CUR_OUT represent multi rows not a single value .

Comment: 1) The GET_user procedure, most likely, opens the cursor, there is no need to open it again(cause of the PLS-00382 error) - remove open CUR_OUT statement; 2) You would need an exit loop condition exit when CUR_OUT%notfound for instance, if you do not want to hang your session forever.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try to execute the procedure like this,

```
var c refcursor;
execute pkg_name.get_user('14232', '15', 'TDWL', 'SA', 1, :c);
print c;
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but it give me this error : Bind Variable "c" is NOT DECLARED
anonymous block completed

Comment: @Samy Louize Hanna, Before executing the proceudre, you need to run `var c refcursor` This mechanism is for assigning values to a variable.

Comment: Error starting at line 3 in command:
execute pkg_name.get_user('14232', '15', 'TDWL', 'SA', 1, :c)
Error report:
ORA-00904: "TDWL": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "schema.PKG_name", line 156
ORA-06512: at line 1
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Line 156 doesn't refer to my stored procedure

Comment: @Samy Louize Hanna, The error message looks like, there is something wrong with your procedure code.

Comment: Line 156 doesn't refer to my stored procedure

Comment: But the error message `ORA-00904:` indicates that, any of your column name entered is either missing or invalid.

Comment: Not working - what is this? You need a DECLARE section.

Comment: @misha, Why you need a DECLARE section to execute a procedure in sql developer? Which client You are using?

Comment: I think it was Oracle SQL Develper. The built in functionality to run a stored procedure auto-fills a declare section. Running a statement similar as the one above was not working, even if you would expect it to naturally work.

Answer (score 10):

Consider you've created a procedure like below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_FULL_NAME like
(
  FIRST_NAME IN VARCHAR2, 
  LAST_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
  FULL_NAME OUT VARCHAR2 
) IS 
BEGIN
  FULL_NAME:= FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME;
END GET_FULL_NAME;
```

In Oracle SQL Developer, you can run this procedure in two ways.

**1. Using SQL Worksheet**

Create a SQL Worksheet and write PL/SQL anonymous block like this and hit f5

```
DECLARE
  FULL_NAME Varchar2(50);
BEGIN
  GET_FULL_NAME('Foo', 'Bar', FULL_NAME);
  Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Full name is: ' || FULL_NAME);
END;
```

**2. Using GUI Controls**

- Expand **Procedures**
- Right click on the procudure you've created and Click **Run**
- In the pop-up window, Fill the parameters and Click **OK**.

Cheers!

Comment: sorry but the number one point gives problem 'identifier FULL_NAME must be declared'

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I believe you may have meant to write "...you can run this procedure in two steps" (i.e., "steps", not "ways").

Answer (score 0):

- execute PROCEDURE_NAME
- execute PRECEDURE_NAME(Parameters)

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing to make more obvious what additional insight you contribute beyond https://stackoverflow.com/a/20186667/7733418 ; ideally according to [answer].

Answer (score -4):

-- If no parameters need to be passed to a procedure, simply:

```
BEGIN
   MY_PACKAGE_NAME.MY_PROCEDURE_NAME
END;
```