# ORACLE call stored procedure inside package with cursor type

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am really struggling with calling stored procedure below. I am using oracle sql developer, version 19.2. What I have tried is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20186667/867703) but I am receiving errors (same errors as described in comments). Why is it so hard to call such a simple stored procedure from sql developer?

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY "PCK_FIRST" IS
      PROCEDURE GET_GETNAMES(
        USER_ID IN NUMBER,    
        M_RESULT OUT TYPES.CURSOR_TYPE
      ) IS
      BEGIN
        OPEN M_RESULT FOR
        SELECT * FROM PER_NAMES WHERE ID = USER_ID;
      END;

END PCK_FIRST;
```

Comment: There are several different errors described in the comments of the answer you're linking to.  What error are you getting specifically?  And how exactly are you calling this procedure.  In your comment to another answer, you indicate that this procedure is in a package.  Is that correct?  And I assume that is different from the `types` package where your `cursor_type` is defined?

Comment: @JustinCave - yes, procedure is inside package. I've edited my code. Sorry, I don't understand the other part of your question about types?

Comment: The declaration of your procedure says that `m_result` is of type `types.cursor_type`.  That implies that you have a `types` package where `cursor_type` is defined.  My guess is that it was defined as a simple weakly typed ref cursor (i.e. it is identical to `sys_refcursor`) but that's just a guess.  What is the code that you're using to call this procedure?  What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: @JustinCave - where is this cursor supposed to be declared? For sure it's in the folder 'Types' - I've checked all the types. The error is:  Bind Variable "c" is NOT DECLARED

Comment: What is the declaration of `cursor_type` in the `types` package?  Is it a simple weakly typed ref cursor?  What is the code you're using to call the procedure?  I'm assuming that's where the variable `c` is being used without being declared.

Comment: @JustinCave - thanks a lot for pointing out that there is also a package TYPES. This cursor is defined like this: TYPE CURSOR_TYPE IS REF CURSOR; There is a lot of packages and I didn't know that cursor can be defined inside package. Thanks again for this. I thought that all types will be visible in folder TYPES. But not, this cursor is defined inside package TYPES.

Comment: @JustinCave - may I please ask you how to make printing more user friendly? If I just use print for cursor, it looks like printing script - I would like it to look like printing data table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable with the type `TYPES.CURSOR_VALUE` and then use that as the output from the cursor:

```sql
DECLARE
  cur    TYPES.CURSOR_TYPE;
  p_id   PER_NAMES.ID%TYPE;
  p_name PER_NAMES.NAME%TYPE;
BEGIN
  PCK_FIRST.get_getnames( 1, cur );
  LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO p_id, p_name;
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( p_id || ': ' || p_name );
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=04cf3c57b4b07a46c72cdbae5c01769c)*

---

If you want to call it in SQL Developer then:

```sql
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;
EXECUTE pck_first.get_getnames(1, :cur);
PRINT cur;
```

And run it as a script using <kbd>F5</kbd> (rather than as individual statements using <kbd>Ctrl-Enter</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks a lot for code, it works. Is there a way to make output look more like datatable output, something like SELECT * FROM PER_NAMES looks like. Print cur gives output and it's ok, but it looks like script output.

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

As first I suggest you to run this then try again to exec your procedure

```
create or replace package types as
   type cursor_type is ref cursor;
end
/
```

**otherwise** try this changing `TYPES.CURSOR_TYPE with sys_refcursor`

```
--example
create table test_user (
   user_id number(19) not null,
   username varchar2(50)
);

insert into test_user values (1, 'user1');

insert into test_user values (2, 'user2');

create or replace procedure test_proc (
   p_user_id in number,
   p_out_rec out sys_refcursor
)
is
   l_out SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin
   open l_out for
      select * 
        from test_user
       where user_id = p_user_id;
end;
/

declare
   l_output sys_refcursor;
   l_userid number := 1;
begin
  test_proc(1, l_output);
end;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Problem is that I can not change stored procedure. It is inside larger package. I would just like to call it the way it is. Why is changing cursor so important?